# Django - render object image from the model itself or use a different model

Tags: django

I'm a bit in doubt regarding on how and what's the best approach for displaying images through `Django`. Of course, not serving the images from the database.

So, for instance, let's take the `User` model that comes out of the box with `Django`. It is not recommended to alter the model, but use a different model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',
                              upload_to='user-profile-pics')
```

Ok. So, this works fine. Now, let's say I have a different model for which I want to store images as well (e.g.: products). This means that for each product I have to store an image.

Is it recommended to use a different model as above or since this is a custom model we can save the image within this model itself? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this model you are not storing any image in the database. You are storing it in a folder named "user-profile-pics" only the image details are stored in the database.

Regarding the second part of your question it depends on the situation and the best design that fit your work.

Comment: That was the reason of my question after all. I am aware of what you are saying.